# Designing XAML UI while using XAML Islands and C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, xaml, c++-winrt

I am trying to make a Windows desktop multimedia program using C++, thinking about which UI library to use. As I tried to target Windows only, Windows-specific technologies like UWP came to my mind. While trying some examples about C++/WinRT, however, recent app packagings like `.appx` and `.msix` bothered me. I don't like how they force developers to sign apps and how they are installed, and I just want to make a project to a single `.msi` installer which can be simply downloaded from my website. Also, I want it to be distributed portably in a zipped file, too.

So I started searching for methods that met my requirements and use pretty recent Microsoft technologies, also with pure C/C++ support excluding C#. Also, I want my program's UI to be designed fully with XAML, separating front-end from main logic.

I think that from several examples both official and unofficial, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-Xaml-Hosting) is the most close sample that meet my needs.

Explanation:

1. Uses traditional Win32 template from Visual Studio
2. Compiles into a stand-alone binary without any dependency errors
3. Has C++/WinRT support for XAML Islands, so that the app can use modern Fluent Design for UI
4. Don't force me to sign app and upload app to Windows Store

So the main advantage is that I can just grab the binary from the output folder and use it. I also liked the way they showed how to play video. However, what I didn't like is how they created app windows. To use XAML technology inside traditional Win32 window, the code basically starts with WinMain and draws XAML inside the window. The problem is that it is too cumbersome work. What I first expected was interacting with `.xaml` files just like when you first create UWP program. If I can use XAML file directly, I would be able to see the design real-time. It would also be more simple. However, I don't know how to set up projects like that.

I know that UWP desktop app **templates** use [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.UI.Xaml/). But they don't come into a single binary when compiled. Old Win32 **templates** are built into a portable binary, but I don't know how to enable XAML UI editor inside them.

I want to know how I can set C++ desktop templates to build XAML UI using Visual Studio XAML editor, separating UI parts from the code. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not sure why would you want to use XAML in native desktop application given how bloated it is, but have you read [Using the UWP XAML hosting API in a C++ Win32 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api#host-a-standard-uwp-control)?

Comment: @VTT Actually I already spent many hours reading and simulating what was written there. The reason I want to use XAML as a UI is just that I somehow like how it looks, and because it does not need external dependencies compared to Qt or wxWidgets.

Comment: The whole point is making the binary as small as possible like old native programs. If that was not my purpose, it would be much easier! (¬‿¬)

Comment: If you have any specific problem then you should describe in the question.

Comment: @VTT Well... I think my problem is pretty specific regarding that I am questioning about  how to set Win32 VS project to use XAML editor.

Comment: The link I've posted in my first comment explains how to set up such a project...

Comment: @VTT I already tried multiple templates and examples Microsoft provided. However, none of them fully met my requirements. Some provided ways to use builtin XAML editor, but their building and installing method was awful. Some provided ways to integrate Win32, but I don't know how to use builtin XAML editor with the project.

Comment: Then you should ask specific question about specific issue with specific project... Also if you are expecting to be able to plop UI in WYSIWYG editor then you'll be disappointed anyway.

Comment: @VTT How I can make a specific question when I haven't written any code? What I need is a method to make a project, not a way to edit code and take care of errors. I understand what you mean, but it's way to hard to explain with only text and I would have to upload 30-40 screenshots to be more specific.

Comment: Also, I wonder what "you'll be disappointed anyway" means.